# How to save python current matplotlib figure into numpy data?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-conversion

I have a 1k by 1k image plotted with mask and labels added to it, and it is being displayed as a matplotlib figure (plt.figure). I want to convert this whole plot into a numpy array but I can't seem to do so. I cannot replicate the whole situation due to the complications of my code by this is an attempt to simplify my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#04_05.png is a 1k by 1k image
data = cv2.imread("04_05.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
figsize=(14, 14)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=figsize)
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(data)

canvas = plt.gca().figure.canvas
canvas.draw()
data = np.frombuffer(canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
image = data.reshape(canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
plt.figure("test")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

In the first section of the code, I read a 1k by 1k image and simulated the changes in the axes by offing the axis of the plot, and this portion of the code should not be touched since this acts as the current plt figure I want to convert into a numpy data.

Second section of the code is my attempt to convert the current plot into a numpy data format. However, when I tried to display the "converted data" (plt.imshow(image)), I found out that there are 2 problems - 1. There are white borders around the image. 2. The dimensions of the image (excluding the white area) is not the same (around 1.2k by 1,2k) as my raw image (1k by 1k). Another thing I noted is that the converted data I obtained is 1.4k by 1.4k in dimensions, which is the same as my figsize of 14 (dpi = 100), which means to say the white area is about 200 pixels in border. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2dAE.png)

Hence, how do I solve this 2 problems or does anyone have another method of converting current plots into numpy data such that when displaying the converted will result in the same dimensions (without white border) as my raw image (1k by 1k)

Comment: A pyplot plot is much more complicated than a numpy array it is drawing. There are a few common ways to store numpy arrays but I haven't heard of any to store a pyplot plot. Usually they store the data and plot parameters, then feed them into a method to make the plot again.

Comment: As for your second problem, you can limit the x and y axes of your plot to omit the white border. If the white border is in the data (and you should check), you could also slice your array to make an array that omits the border's data. You could save that array in a file to save this work for later.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Yes, this was my temporary solution by making the figure size to a big enough number (fig size 14 or 13), such that the area of interest I want is around 1k by 1k  at the center then I slice the array and get the 1k by 1k image I want. But this does not solve my problem entirely since I would have to always guess what figure size to use and manually find out which area to slice out. In addition, if my raw image is a smaller of larger size, I would have to repeat the steps I mentioned earlier all over again, which isn't feasible in the long run..

Comment: This question could be clearer.  Are you just trying to make the image fill the figure?  If you are just trying to make a numpy array why are you using matplotlib at all?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Sorry if the question was not clear. The main question is to make a numpy array from an active matplotlib figure (same dimensions). And the second portion of the code is my attempt to achieve that but I did not manage to do so and 2 other problems arose which I stated in my question (different dimensions + white border around image). Hence, in the last para I stated if those 2 problems can be solved , it will have solved my initial problem or come out with another solution that will solve my initial problem entirely. Hope this is a clearer explanation thank you!